# How to make a dynamic grid in Python

Tags: python, grid

I am building an X's and O's (tic tac toe) application where the user can decide whether the grid is between 5X5 and 10X10, how do I write the code so that the grid is dynamic?

At the moment this is all I have to make a grid of one size:

```
 grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
#defining size
x = y = 5
#create empty list to hold rows
grid = []
#for each row defined by Y, this loop will append a list containing X occurrences of "0"
for row in range(y):
    grid.append(list("0"*x))

print grid
```

Output:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```